# CookiePolicyOptions or CookieAuthenticationOptions?

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core, cookies, startup, asp.net-core-middleware

I'm just starting to get my mind wrapped around some of the .NetCore Identity stuff.  However, there are a few things that I'm still a bit confused on.  In some examples I've seen things like this:

```
services.AddAuthentication("mycookie")
 .AddCookie("mycookie", options => 
  {
     options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true,
     ...
  });

services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options => 
{
   options.HttpOnly = true;
   ...
});
```

Is `CookiePolicyOptions` configuring the defaults and the `CookieAuthorizationOptions` of `AddCookie` overriding the default for that particular cookie?

Also, does the CookiePolicy configuration in the previous example `services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>` have any effect if there is no Cookie Middleware added in Configure? (i.e. `app.UseCookiePolicy();`)

Lastly, if you set up a Cookie Authentication Scheme (as shown in the code snippet), do you need both  `app.UseCookiePolicy()` and `app.UseAuthentication()` middleware?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CookiePolicyOptions` are part of the [Cookie Policy Middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?view=aspnetcore-7.0#cookie-policy-middleware):

> Use CookiePolicyOptions provided to the Cookie Policy Middleware to control global characteristics of cookie processing and hook into cookie processing handlers when cookies are appended or deleted.

`services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>()` doesn't do anything in and of itself. The `CookiePolicyOptions` options are only interrogated within the `CookiePolicyMiddleware` which is injected when you use `app.UseCookiePolicy()`.

As with almost all ASP.NET Core DI, you can specify the options in two ways:

1. Using the overload that allows the options to be specified:

   `app.UseCookiePolicy(new CookiePolicyOptions { HttpOnly = true, ... })`
2. Using a call to `Configure<TOptions>`:

   `services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options => { options.HttpOnly = true; ... });`

In your policy options, you can set a minimum SameSite mode, and whether cookies emitted by your application should be Secure and/or HttpOnly, and configure some callbacks for when consent is needed, and so on.

The middleware will apply that policy to all cookies set by your application, and therefore may override what you configure for your authentication cookie.

See also [the docs linked above](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?view=aspnetcore-7.0#cookie-policy-middleware):

> The Cookie Policy Middleware setting for `MinimumSameSitePolicy` can affect the setting of `Cookie.SameSite` in `CookieAuthenticationOptions` settings according to the matrix below.

| MinimumSameSitePolicy | Cookie.SameSite | Resultant Cookie.SameSite setting |
| --- | --- | --- |
| SameSiteMode.None | SameSiteMode.None SameSiteMode.Lax SameSiteMode.Strict | SameSiteMode.None SameSiteMode.Lax SameSiteMode.Strict |
| SameSiteMode.Lax | SameSiteMode.None SameSiteMode.Lax SameSiteMode.Strict | SameSiteMode.Lax SameSiteMode.Lax SameSiteMode.Strict |
| SameSiteMode.Strict | SameSiteMode.None SameSiteMode.Lax SameSiteMode.Strict | SameSiteMode.Strict SameSiteMode.Strict SameSiteMode.Strict |

Answer (score 3):

The use of cookie authentication in .net core is not itself the Identity membership system, rather a component that could be used as a standalone Authentication means or set up as part of a broader Identity configuration.

Identity -> Namespace: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity

CookieAuthentication -> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies

Identity: [CookieConfiguration in Identity is an extension config method of the service Collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio#scaffold-identity-into-an-mvc-project-with-authorization)

CookieAuth: [CookiePolicyOptions provides programmatic configuration for the CookiePolicyMiddleware.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.cookiepolicyoptions?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

```
 services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options => 
    {
       options.HttpOnly = true;
       ...
    });
```

This part is a set up of the Cookie policy in terms of privacy, GDPR(for Europe) and other policies.

The other part provides means to set up cookies in terms of authorization policy of your application:

```
services.AddAuthentication("mycookie")
 .AddCookie("mycookie", options => 
  {
     options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true,
     ...
  });
```

Unfortunately this is all I have as information. I hope more people can add some deeper understanding of the topic.

EDIT - 2022:

A more comprehensive article : https://www.reddit.com/r/dotnet/comments/we9qx8/a_comprehensive_overview_of_authentication_in/